# how to get posts from facebook page using GraphAPI in swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-graph-api

My app had a functionality which is : get posts from Facebook page and show it in the app. 
i searched and i found that i should use Facebook GraphAPI : 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.3#reading
i follow the previous link, but i get error : 
**"An access token is required to request this resource."**
i have the access token for the page, but i really don't know how to assign it in my request. 
any help please?
thanks a lot!

Comment: passing access Token as Parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Using Facebook SDK.**

LOGIN FACEBOOK BUTTON

```
@IBAction func click_Facebook(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        let loginView : FBSDKLoginManager = FBSDKLoginManager()

        loginView.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehavior.Browser

        loginView.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile","user_friends","user_photos","user_location","user_education_history","user_birthday","user_posts"], handler: { (result : FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error : NSError!) -> Void in

                if ((error) != nil)
                {
                    // Process error

                    self.alertWithMessaage(error.localizedDescription)
                }
                else if result.isCancelled {
                    // Handle cancellations
                }
                else {

                    self.returnUserData()
                }

        })

    }
```

After login calling the below function.

```
    var Requset : FBSDKGraphRequest

    println("\(FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken())")

    var acessToken = String(format:"%@", FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString) as String

    println("\(acessToken)")

    var parameters1 = ["access_token":FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString]


    Requset  = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath:"me/posts", parameters:parameters1, HTTPMethod:"GET")

    Requset.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        MBProgressHUD.hideHUDForView(appDelegate.window, animated: true)

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            println("Error: \(error)")
        }
        else
        {
            println("fetched user: \(result)")

            var dataDict: AnyObject = result!.objectForKey("data")!

        }
    })
}
```

**2. Using Default Facebook App.**

**// Get Access TOKEN**

```
    var _accountStore: ACAccountStore = ACAccountStore()

    var accountType : ACAccountType = _accountStore.accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier(ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook)!

    var accounts : NSArray = _accountStore.accountsWithAccountType(accountType)!

    var facebookAccount1: ACAccount = accounts.lastObject! as ACAccount

    println("== \(facebookAccount1.credential.oauthToken)")
```

**// Pass AccessToken To Parameter**

```
    var acessToken = String(format:"%@", facebookAccount1.credential.oauthToken) as String

    var parameters = ["access_token":acessToken] as NSDictionary
```

**//SLRequset**

```
    var imageURL : NSURL = NSURL(string: "Your graph URL")!

    println("=== TOKEN : \(LoginService().currentAccount?.credential.oauthToken)")

    var Requset = SLRequest(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook, requestMethod: SLRequestMethod.GET, URL: imageURL, parameters: parameters)

    Requset.account = account

    Requset.performRequestWithHandler { (responseData : NSData!, urlResponse : NSHTTPURLResponse!, error : NSError!) -> Void in


        if (error != nil)
        {
            self.alertWithMessaage(error.localizedDescription)
        }
        else{

            var datastring = NSString(data: responseData, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            println("== \(datastring)")

            var error:NSError? = nil

            var UserDict = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(responseData, options:nil, error: &error) as? NSDictionary


        }

    }
```

Comment: hey 
thank you sooo mush for ur answer, 
but i have a problem in getting access token, can u explain how you get it ?
i get it from https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer
but after a while this access token dosen't work , the error was:
(expiry time for it is over) 
so i have to renew it.
can you tell me how u get it ?

Comment: Login with Facebook form Your Setting in Iphone.

Comment: if the user didn't login from setting, what will happen ?
and another question: 
i apply ur code, but in run time i get an exception in "facebookAccount1". the error is : 
unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
why ?

Comment: Best way Want to use FacebookSDK 4.1.

Comment: I am update How to get AccessToken when use Facebook Sdk

Comment: thank you, this access token for the facebook page or for my account ? :|
now i notice when i read step by step ur code, it seems like u get the access token for the account not for fb page. right ?
i need in this request the access token for the fb page. :S

Comment: thank you soooo mush! best answer !
but if the path was : 
page_id/posts
here i need access token for the facebook page right ?
how to get it ?

Answer (score 0):

> **Swift 4.2 Update Code**

in your viewDidLoad() 
create faceBook Button for Login and Logout.

```
 let loginButton = FBLoginButton(permissions: [ .publicProfile, .email, .userPosts, .userPhotos])
    loginButton.center = view.center
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
```

Now Create Function to get FaceBook Posts

```
 func getPosts() {

    let accessToken = AccessToken.current?.tokenString
    let params = ["access_token" : accessToken ?? ""]

    let request = GraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/posts/", parameters: params, httpMethod: .get)

    request.start(completionHandler: { (test, result, error) in
        if(error == nil)
        {
           print(result!)
        }
    })

}
```

In result you will get Data of your facebook posts!